# Trying to write a simple encrypt/decrypt function in php

Tags: php, encryption, mcrypt

I want to create an 'activation' key when someone joins my website. This will be emailed to them and when they click the link it will activate their account. I want to incorporate some information in the activation key (nothing major from a security point of view - simply what page they were on when they registered etc so I can redirect them back to that page).

I have the following:

```
// THIS TO ENCRYPT THE DATA
$secret_key = "This is my SeCrEt key";
$etype = MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256;
$iv = mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_get_iv_size($etype, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB), MCRYPT_RAND);
$output = mcrypt_encrypt($etype, $secret_key, $string_to_encrypt, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);
$output = base64_encode ($output);
$output = urlencode($output);


// THIS TO DECRYPT THE DATA - THIS ISN'T WORKING?
$secret_key = "This is my SeCrEt key";
$etype = MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256;
$iv = mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_get_iv_size($etype, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB), MCRYPT_RAND);

$string_to_decrypt = urldecode($string_to_decrypt);
$string_to_decrypt = base64_decode($string_to_decrypt);
$output = mcrypt_decrypt($etype, $secret_key, $string_to_decrypt, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);
```

I am using the base64 encoding and urlencoding because I'll be emailing the link.

The decryption doesn't work at all. Any ideas?

Comment: Just a suggestion; you could also just use a random code like `sha1(mt_rand(1,999999))` and just save related information in the database. It doesn't really make sense to me to use all kinds of encryption for an activation code...

Comment: @Bram, it's just so that I can 'decode' it to leave me with the relevant information. I need to be able to decode whatever I use. Thank ;-)

Comment: The IV must be the same for a particular encryption/decryption.

Comment: @YolandaRuiz That sorted it thanks. Add it as an answer and I'll tick it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IV must be the same for a particular encryption/decryption.